# CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync Win 8.1 doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, in-app-purchase, windows-8.1

Calling the new

```
var result = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("id");
```

doesn't work in Windows 8.1?

But when I call `await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("id", false);` it does work though this method is depreciated and I need the result for consumable In-Apps.

Also by "doesn't work" I mean nothing happens.  It doesn't bring up the testing popup windows for "CurrentAppSimulator" and just fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test product ID was just not set right... silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:  Run the app once calling any method on CurrentAppSimulator.  Close your app and look at the WindowsStoreProxy.XML file that the simulator creates in your app folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\\LocalState\Microsoft\Windows Store\ApiData\WindowsStoreProxy.xml.

This file is created in UTF-16 format.  If you take this file and edit it you will have better luck than if you try to create your own file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator has more details.

Last tip is to remember that this file is never written to.  you have to edit it to setup each scenario.

And you'll also have better luck if you create and deploy your own copy for testing.

For me, the file would load but no functions worked when I had it save just a plain ascii file or even after changing it to UTF-8.  Had to be saved as UTF-16 to work end-to-end.  It would have been nice if the simulator had given some feedback on the ReloadAsync call to save me hours of pain and frustration.